# Chrome browser: Two tab search drop-down menus. How to disable any of them?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, gui

I am using Chrome 116.0.5845.82 beta (64-bit) and a few days ago [I ended up with two tab search drop-down menus](https://imgur.com/gallery/PiCcRcG).

There is no *chrome://flags/#enable-tab-search* for me to disable.
How can I disable one or both of them?

Comment: Beta version means a slightly tested version that is not stable enough for a release. Install the Chrome stable version instead.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine, Chrome just updated to stable release v116.0.5845.141 and it has two Tab Search dropdown menus (the original one on the right of the open tabs and now one on the left of the open tabs). Looks like the Chrome dev team let this bug slip through to the official release (and worse, with no obvious setting to deactivate it).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).